# Turn a table into a block element on mobile/tablet screens and transform columns into rows [Responsive Design]

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive-design

guys, I need help with transforming my table's columns into respective rows on mobile/tablet screens for better UX. I've attached the code where I'm stuck and a picture of what I hope to achieve at this point. I would appreciate your advice.
[I want table columns to transform into respective rows as depicted in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAc6h.png)

```css
.product-overview-table {
  margin: 30px 0;
  width:100%;
}
.product-overview-table thead {
  background: #F9BA32;
  color: #fff;
}
.product-overview-table,
.product-overview-table td,
.product-overview-table th {
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}
.product-overview-table thead th {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
.product-overview-table tr {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-wrap: wrap !important;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.product-overview-table tbody tr:hover {
  transform: scale(1.02);
  transition: 0.3s;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.product-overview-table tbody tr {
  border: 2px solid #e1e1e1;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.product-overview-table tr td:first-child,
.product-overview-table tr th:first-child {
  width: 20%;
}
.product-overview-table tr td:nth-child(2),
.product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 20%;
}
.product-overview-table tr td:nth-child(3),
.product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 10%;
}
.product-overview-table tr td:nth-child(4),
.product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(4) {
  width: 10%;
}
.product-overview-table tr td:nth-child(5),
.product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(5) {
  width: 10%;
}
.product-overview-table tr td:nth-child(6),
.product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(6) {
  width: 10%;
}
.product-overview-table tr td:last-child,
.product-overview-table tr th:last-child {
  width: 20%;
}
.product-overview-table .product-image {
  position: relative;
}
.product-overview-table .p_tag {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: 0;
  background: #5898ff;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.product-overview-table .p_tag::after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  bottom: -7px;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) #133091 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-style: inset solid inset inset;
  border-width: 0 10px 7px;
}

.product-overview-table .p-img {
  width: 90%;
  max-height: 140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}
.product-overview-table .product-title .p_title {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4b77b7;
  text-align: center;
}
.product-overview-table .product-btn a {
  background: #D32F2F;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.product-overview-table .product-btn a:hover {
  background: #000;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.product-overview-table .product-feature {
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 10;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  text-align: center;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .product-overview-table .p_tag {
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    top: -10px;
  }
  .product-overview-table tbody tr {
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .product-overview-table tr td:first-child {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .product-overview-table tr td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .product-overview-table tr td:last-child,
  .product-overview-table tr th:last-child {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .product-overview-table .product-btn a {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(2) {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .product-overview-table tr th:first-child,
  .product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(2),
  .product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(3),
  .product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(4),
  .product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(5),
  .product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(6),
  .product-overview-table tr th:last-child {
    display: none;
  }
  
  td:not(:first-child):before {
    color: #91ced4;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    tax-align:left;
    float: left;
  }
  
  .product-overview-table td:nth-child(3),
  .product-overview-table td:nth-child(4),
  .product-overview-table td:nth-child(5),
  .product-overview-table td:nth-child(6) {
    tax-align:left;
    float: left;
  }

  td:nth-child(3):before {
    content: "Material:";
  }
  td:nth-child(4):before {
    content: "Wheel:";
  }
  td:nth-child(5):before {
    content: "Capacity:";
  }
  td:nth-child(6):before {
    content: "Colors:";
  }
}

/* End Affiliate Product Box */
```

```html
<table class="product-overview-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Preview</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Material</th>
      <th>Wheel</th>
      <th>Capacity</th>
      <th>Colors</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="product-image">
        <div class="p_tag">
          Top Pick
        </div>
        <a href="#" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
          <img src="https://redkosports.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Redko-Sports-About-Slider-Background.png" class="p-img">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="product-title">
        <a href="#" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
          <div class="p_title">
            SkateXS Personalized Street Skateboard
          </div>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="product-feature">
        Bamboo
      </td>
      <td class="product-feature">
        Polyurethane </td>
      <td class="product-feature">
        250 lbs
      </td>
      <td class="product-feature">
        24
      </td>
      <td class="product-btn">
        <a href="#" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Check Price
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <style>
  </style>
</table>
```

strong text

Comment: In the media queries, set tr flex-direction column and remove all the widths of nth child 3, 4, 5.

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my proposition for You..I hope You will be content :-)

```css
.product-overview-table {
  margin: 30px 0;
  width:100%;
}
.product-overview-table thead {
  background: #F9BA32;
  color: #fff;
}
.product-overview-table,
.product-overview-table td,
.product-overview-table th {
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}
.product-overview-table thead th {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
.product-overview-table tr {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-wrap: wrap !important;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.product-overview-table tbody tr:hover {
  transform: scale(1.02);
  transition: 0.3s;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.product-overview-table tbody tr {
  border: 2px solid #e1e1e1;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.product-overview-table tr td:first-child,
.product-overview-table tr th:first-child {
  width: 20%;
}
.product-overview-table tr td:nth-child(2),
.product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 20%;
}
.product-overview-table tr td:nth-child(3),
.product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 10%;
}
.product-overview-table tr td:nth-child(4),
.product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(4) {
  width: 10%;
}
.product-overview-table tr td:nth-child(5),
.product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(5) {
  width: 10%;
}
.product-overview-table tr td:nth-child(6),
.product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(6) {
  width: 10%;
}
.product-overview-table tr td:last-child,
.product-overview-table tr th:last-child {
  width: 20%;
}
.product-overview-table .product-image {
  position: relative;
}
.product-overview-table .p_tag {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: 0;
  background: #5898ff;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.product-overview-table .p_tag::after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  bottom: -7px;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) #133091 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-style: inset solid inset inset;
  border-width: 0 10px 7px;
}

.product-overview-table .p-img {
  width: 90%;
  max-height: 140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}
.product-overview-table .product-title .p_title {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4b77b7;
  text-align: center;
}
.product-overview-table .product-btn a {
  background: #D32F2F;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.product-overview-table .product-btn a:hover {
  background: #000;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.product-overview-table .product-feature {
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 10;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  text-align: center;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  
  .product-overview-table tr {
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items:ce;
  }
 
  .product-overview-table tr td:nth-child(4) {
    width: 25%;
  }
  
  .product-overview-table tr td:nth-child(3) {
    width: 25%;
  }
  
  .product-overview-table tr td:nth-child(5) {
    width: 25%;
  }
  
  .product-overview-table tr td:nth-child(6) {
    width: 25%;
  }
  
  
  
  .product-overview-table .p_tag {
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    top: -10px;
  }
  .product-overview-table tbody tr {
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  .product-overview-table tr td:first-child {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .product-overview-table tr td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .product-overview-table tr td:last-child,
  .product-overview-table tr th:last-child {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .product-overview-table .product-btn a {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(2) {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .product-overview-table tr th:first-child,
  .product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(2),
  .product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(3),
  .product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(4),
  .product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(5),
  .product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(6),
  .product-overview-table tr th:last-child {
    display: none;
  }
  
  td:not(:first-child):before {
    color: #91ced4;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    tax-align:left;
    float: left;
  }
  
  .product-overview-table td:nth-child(3),
  .product-overview-table td:nth-child(4),
  .product-overview-table td:nth-child(5),
  .product-overview-table td:nth-child(6) {
    tax-align:left;
    float: left;
  }

  td:nth-child(3):before {
    content: "Material:";
  }
  td:nth-child(4):before {
    content: "Wheel:";
  }
  td:nth-child(5):before {
    content: "Capacity:";
  }
  td:nth-child(6):before {
    content: "Colors:";
  }
  
}
```

```html
<table class="product-overview-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Preview</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Material</th>
      <th>Wheel</th>
      <th>Capacity</th>
      <th>Colors</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="product-image">
        <div class="p_tag">
          Top Pick
        </div>
        <a href="#" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
          <img src="https://redkosports.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Redko-Sports-About-Slider-Background.png" class="p-img">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="product-title">
        <a href="#" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
          <div class="p_title">
            SkateXS Personalized Street Skateboard
          </div>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="product-feature">
        Bamboo
      </td>
      <td class="product-feature">
        Polyurethane </td>
      <td class="product-feature">
        250 lbs
      </td>
      <td class="product-feature">
        24
      </td>
      <td class="product-btn">
        <a href="#" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Check Price
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <style>
  </style>
</table>
```

Comment: You're welcome ;-) @Liam Noah

Answer (score 0):

```css
.product-overview-table {
  margin: 30px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.product-overview-table thead {
  background: #F9BA32;
  color: #fff;
}

.product-overview-table,
.product-overview-table td,
.product-overview-table th {
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}

.product-overview-table thead th {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

.product-overview-table tr {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-wrap: wrap !important;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.product-overview-table tbody tr:hover {
  transform: scale(1.02);
  transition: 0.3s;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.product-overview-table tbody tr {
  border: 2px solid #e1e1e1;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.product-overview-table tr td:first-child,
.product-overview-table tr th:first-child {
  width: 20%;
}

.product-overview-table tr td:nth-child(2),
.product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 20%;
}

.product-overview-table tr td:nth-child(3),
.product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 10%;
}

.product-overview-table tr td:nth-child(4),
.product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(4) {
  width: 10%;
}

.product-overview-table tr td:nth-child(5),
.product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(5) {
  width: 10%;
}

.product-overview-table tr td:nth-child(6),
.product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(6) {
  width: 10%;
}

.product-overview-table tr td:last-child,
.product-overview-table tr th:last-child {
  width: 20%;
}

.product-overview-table .product-image {
  position: relative;
}

.product-overview-table .p_tag {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: 0;
  background: #5898ff;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.product-overview-table .p_tag::after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  bottom: -7px;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) #133091 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-style: inset solid inset inset;
  border-width: 0 10px 7px;
}

.product-overview-table .p-img {
  width: 90%;
  max-height: 140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.product-overview-table .product-title .p_title {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4b77b7;
  text-align: center;
}

.product-overview-table .product-btn a {
  background: #D32F2F;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.product-overview-table .product-btn a:hover {
  background: #000;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.product-overview-table .product-feature {
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 10;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .product-overview-table .p_tag {
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    top: -10px;
  }
  .product-overview-table tbody tr {
    padding: 10px;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .product-overview-table tr td:first-child {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .product-overview-table tr td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .product-overview-table tr td:last-child,
  .product-overview-table tr th:last-child {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .product-overview-table .product-btn a {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(2) {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .product-overview-table tr th:first-child,
  .product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(2),
  .product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(3),
  .product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(4),
  .product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(5),
  .product-overview-table tr th:nth-child(6),
  .product-overview-table tr th:last-child {
    display: none;
  }
  td:not(:first-child):before {
    color: #91ced4;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    tax-align: left;
    float: left;
  }
  .product-overview-table tr td:nth-child(3),
  .product-overview-table tr td:nth-child(4),
  .product-overview-table tr td:nth-child(5),
  .product-overview-table tr td:nth-child(6) {
    width: 100%;
  }
  td:nth-child(3):before {
    content: "Material:";
  }
  td:nth-child(4):before {
    content: "Wheel:";
  }
  td:nth-child(5):before {
    content: "Capacity:";
  }
  td:nth-child(6):before {
    content: "Colors:";
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="product-overview-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Preview</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Material</th>
      <th>Wheel</th>
      <th>Capacity</th>
      <th>Colors</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="product-image">
        <div class="p_tag">
          Top Pick
        </div>
        <a href="#" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
          <img src="https://redkosports.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Redko-Sports-About-Slider-Background.png" class="p-img">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="product-title">
        <a href="#" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
          <div class="p_title">
            SkateXS Personalized Street Skateboard
          </div>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="product-feature">
        Bamboo
      </td>
      <td class="product-feature">
        Polyurethane </td>
      <td class="product-feature">
        250 lbs
      </td>
      <td class="product-feature">
        24
      </td>
      <td class="product-btn">
        <a href="#" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Check Price
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I modified a bit of CSS.

Comment: Really appreciate your input @Servesh